# Unexpected Internal server error for the post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, mern

```
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const Voter = require('../Models/voter');

const voterJwtSecret = 'B7bsTn3lWbZtYpP9';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    designation: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'images');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, uuidv4() + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    const allowedFileTypes = ['images/jpeg', 'images/png', 'images/jpg'];
    if (allowedFileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
        cb(null, true);
    }
    else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
}
let upload = multer({ storage, fileFilter });

// Voter Sign Up
exports.voter_create = [
    body('name')
        .trim()
        .isLength({ min: 3 })
        .escape()
        .withMessage("Specify correct name")
        .isAlphanumeric()
        .withMessage("Name should not have non-alphanumeric characters"),
    body('email')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Email is required.')
        .isEmail()
        .withMessage('Invalid email format.'),
    body('password').notEmpty().withMessage('Password is required.')
        .isLength({ min: 8 }).withMessage('Password must be at least 8 characters.'),
    body('cnic').notEmpty().withMessage('CNIC is required.')
        .isLength({ min: 13, max: 15 }).withMessage('Enter valid cnic'),
    body('constituency').isMongoId().withMessage('Invalid reference of constituency'),
    upload.single('photo'),
    asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
        const user = await Voter.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User with that email already exists' });
        }
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        let secPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
        const voter = new Voter({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: secPassword,
            cnic: req.body.cnic,
            constituency: req.body.constituency,
            pic: req.file.filename
        })
        await voter.save();
        return res.status(200).json({ message: 'success' });
    })
]
```

This controller function is on /elections/voter/signup. When I made post request request to it, it gives me internal server error.

[image]

Backend server is properly running on port 5000.

I as a beginner think it should work but there are no more details when I hit the post request so it is becoming difficult for me to trace error.

Comment: The error should be visible in the server console as it occurs.

Comment: Error will occour of course if something will run but here doesnot respond for this api .Rest are running good